# WPF, Control. Stack of values for dependency property

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I've stuck with one pretty trivial problem (at first look).
Simplified version of my situation looks like this:

I want multiple `Background`(for example) colors to be applied to SAME `Control` and to be able to clear only some of them (by condition). `WPF` does not offer such capability, I can set only one value for each `DP`.

So, I want to apply `Yellow` then `Green` then `Red` colors successively to `Control` object and then be able to reset `Red` so that Control will be with `Green` background (on the other hand, reseting `Green` leaves background `Red`). Looks pretty simple, have you ever created such Decorator for Control? I believe `DP` internally use such behavior, but there are no public APIs for it.

Please, do not suggest using triggers or any other kinds of conditional `DP` setting, I really need to set multiple values for single `DP` and to be able to manage them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a good idea to say "do not suggest" ... Anyway, Well its not possible, and WPF does not do this, what you might meant is the value [precendence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx#value_determination) but this [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing) is fixed, you can't just add another layer in between, for good reasons. The whole system relys on that. Otherwise you could not set one value and use triggers to override it and don't need to take care of resetting the value. Also animations, Style inheritence etc. wouldn't be possible if people start to mess with this list.

So you don't like the trigger idea ... Why? Its exactly for that.
Ok, if you don't like it, how about adding an attached property for `Background1`, `Background2` etc. You also could make Background as an attached property and make it inheritable. You could make an attached behavior, listen to property changes and modify your Background color. You could use a MultiBinding or PriorityBinding. 
Well alot of stuff is possible if the obvious solution is not desired :)

Comment: I just can not use triggers because of implementation details, that's why I asked not to suggest them :)

Comment: How about binding background to a number from your data context, use a value converter to convert the number to a predefined list of colors, so that the converter returns the color you want. Thats one way to solve it.

Comment: Number of colors is not limited, but I'll think about such solution, thanks